# incompatible character encodings with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf, kaminari

Extracted source (around line #125):

```
</table><!-- accordion -->
<div class="row">
<div class="eleven columns alpha">
    <%= paginate @tickets, :params => @search %>
</div><!-- 11.columns.omega -->
</div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

My @ticket uses mailman to download messages. so of them have chinese character and it's causing this issue. Why is is showing this in kaminari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should specify encoding in your kaminari template

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

**PS**

As far you use ERB, you should do it as a ERB comment, I suppose

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>
```

Comment: is this in _paginator.html.erb? the top line?